# Moving highlighted text to another file

Tags: key-bindings, ex-mode

I have no idea how to do this, but here's my idea:  Highlight some text in visual mode, type an ex command and a file name.  *It takes that highlighted text, deletes it, and appends it to the file you specify, creating it if it doesn't already exist.*

I've italicized the parts I don't know how to do.

Comment: There are a number of ways to achieve this. What operating system are you on? Do you require a cross-platform solution? Do you want the new file to be opened in Vim? Or do you need it *not* to be opened in Vim? Or do you not care much either way?

Comment: Also (and this is just me being nosy, so feel free not to answer), what are you actually using the command for?

Comment: @Rich I'm using vim on cygwin (windows 10).  I have a big file of esoteric code (there won't be a plugin for it) that I want to break up into small files.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the advice of @SunnyPun and @Rich, I came up with this:

```
command! -nargs=1 -range -complete=file Move '<,'>w! >> <args>|'<,'>d
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extremely simplified version as a function (run it in Vim to test):

#### Hopefully Inspiring Function

Assuming that `tee` is working on your machine:

```
:function! PasteTo(path)
:  silent execute ":'<,'>w !tee -a ".a:path
:  normal! gvd
:endfunction
```

Then, select some text with linewise Visual mode, and do `:call PasteTo('a.txt')`

**(You'll need to press `<C-u>` to clear that `:'<,'>` inserted)**

The lines are gone and you can do `:vnew a.txt` to see them there.  Try it to see if it also appends.

Explanation: First line appends the lines to the file.  Second one deletes the lines. (By `gv` to repeat selection and `d` to use visual delete)

#### Making that an Ex Command

```
:command! -nargs=1 Cap call PasteTo(<q-args>)
```

Then, you can use `:Cap a.txt` (short form for cut and paste).

#### Questions

1. It is strange if I have forgotten to press `<C-u>`... like if I selected 2 lines the text will be pasted twice.  And extra lines deleted?  What happened?

   It runs for each selected line -- so when I selected 2, it copies and deletes once, and when the function is called for the 2nd line, it copies again and deletes again!  You may want to do a mapping so `<C-u>` is pressed before you "enter" `:Cap`, or investigate for other ways to make your function works nicely with Visual mode.
2. Even if I just character-wise select, it copies the whole line.. [How to get visually selected text in VimScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533565/how-to-get-visually-selected-text-in-vimscript)? (xolox is promising, I'm using his easytags plugin).

Hope this helps and hope I have given enough rope...

Comment: Why use `tee`? `cat >> blah` seems simpler?

Comment: Because it seems to me that `:'<,'>w !cmd` will append the contents at the end of the command.. I tried `blah <<` (lol) and `awk` but can't make the file name come _before_ the contents.  I know I must have missed something obvious but all I have on my hands is `tee` now..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but `'<,'>w !cat >> blah.txt` works for me, appending the current visual selection to the file blah.txt `:w !` writes to stdout and `cat` without a filename reads from `stdin`.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to shell out. So long as `blah.txt` isn't open in Vim, `:'<,'>w! >> blah.txt` works fine. Possibly that's a different answer, though.

Comment: @Rich your comment seems like the most straight forward way to do the whole thing.  Thanks a lot